# Homebrew started blowing up, no idea why

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I probably did some unwise things. After a `brew update` and a `brew doctor` kept throwing the same error, I tried to uninstall and reinstall it with the shell scripts for those. They mostly worked, but upon reinstall, I got the same error bookended by the normal homebrew install output. So now in addition to losing homebrew itself, I've lost all the brew-installed tools. It's unclear what I've screwed up to cause this. Error output below:

```
Pomelo:local john$ brew update
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    14: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    13: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:50:in `available_locales'
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:80:in `init_translations'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `load_translations'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `each'
     8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `block in load_translations'
     7: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:226:in `load_file'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:243:in `load_yml'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:577:in `load_file'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:577:in `open'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:578:in `block in load_file'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:277:in `load'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:455:in `parse_stream': uninitialized constant Psych::Handlers (NameError)
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:50:in `available_locales'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:80:in `init_translations'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `load_translations'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `each'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:18:in `block in load_translations'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:226:in `load_file'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:241:in `load_yml'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/i18n-1.8.3/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:245:in `rescue in load_yml': can not load translations from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: #<NameError: uninitialized constant Psych::Handlers> (I18n::InvalidLocaleData)
```

Comment: Can you upload the actual file to github gist or do less cropping? Is shell segfaulting? Ruby crashing? If I couldn’t get better info, I’d guess you want to chase down your ruby - make sure the system version is being called if you can’t step the brew scripts through the debugger.

Comment: Have you completely uninstalled Brew and tried reinstalling it? This may work!

Comment: @jmh Yes, I've tried that.

Comment: @bmike No segfaults... this is the brew executable giving that out. Ruby, I guess. Looks like the /usr/bin/ruby is being called here, I'm assuming that's the system one (I've never installed another). And the code block should be scrollable.

Comment: The first line of your output already truncates the good stuff. I don’t want to see lower, but higher. No need to post it, just most people won’t be able to help with the window you provided since the good stuff is edited out already.

Comment: @bmike Added the full command with output. Doesn't add anything but the prompt. Do you want the full uninstall/reinstall cycle?

Comment: you might be better off at https://discourse.brew.sh

Comment: @ankii I'm annoyed with having to create a login for yet another site. Might try that the more desperate I become.

Comment: What’s brew doctor saying?

Comment: @JBallin It was saying the same exact output. The people over on Discourse had me manually do the removes that the uninstall was missing, then reinstalling fixed it. Now just 6 months of realizing what tools got removed and brew-installing those one at a time.

Comment: Got it - may be helpful to explain how you manually uninstalled as an answer here. Btw you may be interested in this tool I made, which will back up a log of your local setup, including what you’ve brew installed: https://github.com/JBallin/ballin-scripts (check out the “gu” command).